# Why does Schofield hear church bells when the church is on fire?

Tags: plot-explanation, 1917

In the middle of *1917*, Schofield is in Ècoust. He sees a church on fire and then hides in a French woman's apartment. There he hears bell ringings. Which bells are these? The church is on fire, the city is in ruins and is on fire. Does the plot in any way describe this topic?

[image: the church is on fire]

Comment: Just because it’s burning doesn’t mean the metal bell, which might be enforced into a stone bell tower couldn’t still ring. Some debris might have fallen yanking the rope and causing the bell to ring. Another possibility is a town alarm bell. It may not be a church bell running but an old alarm bell somewhere else near the church.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Schofield counts bell struks to ascertain what time is it. So it isn't debris falls yanking the rope. But no one in their right mind would struck the bell in chapel which is on fire.

Comment: was it that church that was ringing the bell? Also a possibility it was a church nearby, within earshot.